# Parsing Message with Varying Fields

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a byte stream that represents a message in my application. There are 5 fields in the message for demonstration. The first byte in the stream indicates which message fields are present for the current stream. For instance `0x2` in the byte-0 means only the Field-1 is present for the current stream.

The mask field might have 2^5=32 different values. To parse this varying width of message, I wrote the example structure and parser below. My question is, is there any other way to parse such dynamically changing fields? If the message had 64 fields with I would have to write 64 cases, which is cumbersome.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t iDummy0;
    int iDummy1;
}__attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))Field4;

typedef struct
{
    int iField0;
    uint8_t ui8Field1;
    short i16Field2;
    long long i64Field3;
    Field4 stField4;
}__attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))MessageStream;

char* constructIncomingMessage()
{
    char* cpStream = new char(1+sizeof(MessageStream)); // Demonstrative message byte array
                                                            // 1 byte for Mask, 20 bytes for messageStream

    cpStream[0] = 0x1F; // the 0-th byte is a mask marking
                                // which fields are present for the messageStream
                                // all 5 fields are present for the example
    return cpStream;
}

void deleteMessage( char* cpMessage)
{
    delete cpMessage;
}

int main() {
    MessageStream messageStream; // Local storage for messageStream
    uint8_t ui8FieldMask; // Mask to indicate which fields of messageStream
                            // are present for the current incoming message
    const uint8_t ui8BitIsolator = 0x01;
    uint8_t ui8FieldPresent; // ANDed result of Mask and Isolator

    std::size_t szParsedByteCount = 0; // Total number of parsed bytes

    const std::size_t szMaxMessageFieldCount = 5; // There can be maximum 5 fields in
                                                    // the messageStream

    char* cpMessageStream = constructIncomingMessage();
    ui8FieldMask = (uint8_t)cpMessageStream[0];
    szParsedByteCount += 1;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<szMaxMessageFieldCount; ++i)
    {
        ui8FieldPresent = ui8FieldMask & ui8BitIsolator;

        if(ui8FieldPresent)
        {
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    memcpy(&messageStream.iField0, cpMessageStream+szParsedByteCount, sizeof(messageStream.iField0));
                    szParsedByteCount += sizeof(messageStream.iField0);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    memcpy(&messageStream.ui8Field1, cpMessageStream+szParsedByteCount, sizeof(messageStream.ui8Field1));
                    szParsedByteCount += sizeof(messageStream.ui8Field1);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    memcpy(&messageStream.i16Field2, cpMessageStream+szParsedByteCount, sizeof(messageStream.i16Field2));
                    szParsedByteCount += sizeof(messageStream.i16Field2);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    memcpy(&messageStream.i64Field3, cpMessageStream+szParsedByteCount, sizeof(messageStream.i64Field3));
                    szParsedByteCount += sizeof(messageStream.i64Field3);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    memcpy(&messageStream.stField4, cpMessageStream+szParsedByteCount, sizeof(messageStream.stField4));
                    szParsedByteCount += sizeof(messageStream.stField4);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    std::cerr << "Undefined Message field number: " << i << '\n';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ui8FieldMask >>= 1; // shift the mask
    }

    delete deleteMessage(cpMessageStream);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `deleteMessage` suggests you're coming from a C background. Are you familiar enough with C++ to deal with templates?

Comment: The application is in C++, so yes anything in c++ would be perfectly fine. Applications in C are also fine as I can convert them to C.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd change is to drop the `__attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))` on Field4. This is a hack to create structures which mirror a packed wire-format, but that's not the format you're dealing with anyway.

Next, I'd make MessageStream a `std::tuple` of `std::optional<T>` fields.

You now know that there are `std::tuple_size<MessageStream>` possible bits in the mask. Obviously you can't fit 64 bits in a `ui8FieldMask` but I'll assume that's a trivial problem to solve.

You *can* write a for-loop from 0 to `std::tuple_size<MessageStream>` to extract the bits from `ui8FieldMask` to see which bits are set. The slight problem with that logic is that you'll need compile-time constants `I` for `std::get<size_t I>(MessageStream)`, and a for-loop only gives you run-time variables.

Hence, you'll need a recursive `template <size_t I> extract(char const*& cpMessageStream, MessageStream&)`, and of course a specialization `extract<0>`. In `extract<I>`, you can use `typename std::tuple_element<I, MessageStream>::type` to get the `std::optional<T>` at the I'th position in your `MessageStream`.

Comment: Regarding turning MessageStream to a `std::tuple`, it will be a tuple of (for instance) 64 elements with `std::optional<T>` types right? I didn't understand the specialization of `extract<0>`.

Comment: @ErdemTuna: The specialization is your normal end-of-recursion logic. `extract<I>` calls `extract<I-1>` before checking the `I`'th bit of the mask. But `extract<0>` should not call `extract<-1>` obviously.

Comment: Ah okay the stop condition, I thought something else, thank you.

Comment: I am still thinking on the solution, how can I make tuple with `std::optional<T>`  fields? I suppose I have to write every distinct type in the message, i.e. `int`s,  `uint8`s, custom structs and others? The compiler is c++98 compliant, I can't implement it anyway, but I am trying to understand the approach.

Comment: @ErdemTuna: Not just every type, but every field. A tuple is like a struct, but with numbered fields instead of named fields. With C++98 you have a major issue though, that's 22 years old. It doesn't have `std::tuple`.